# How to check if one string contains in another string in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if one string contains in another string in js or jquery
For example : String str1 = asbf_000.String str2 = asbf;
Then str1.contains(str2) should return true.I tried using includes() in JS but did not work

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? your code? what issue you faced

Comment: I tried using str1.includes(str2) for the same string i mentioned earlier and alerted it returned false.

Answer (score 2):

"contains" is not a function is javascript, but "includes" is.
You can use it like

```
let str1 = "asbf_000";
let str2 = "asbf";
const isSubstring = str1.includes(str2);
console.log(isSubstring); // this will log true in the console
```

You can check a working demo here on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9qm5e1x/)

Answer (score 2):

You can check it using `indexOf()` function by checking `str1.indexOf(str2)`

```js
var str1 = 'asbf_000'
var str2 = 'asbf';
console.log(checkExistOrnot(str1,str2))

function checkExistOrnot(str1,str2)
{
 if (str1.indexOf(str2) >= 0)
  return true
 else
   return false
}
```

Comment: If these are the strings var str1 = "hidUnfiledAmt_000";
  var str2 = "spanId_UnfiledAmt_Amt" then it fails

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check substring is by using method "indexOf".

```
<script>
    function subString(str1,str2){
       return str1.indexOf(str2)
    }
    var result = subString("asbf_000","asbf");
</script>
```

if result is greater then -1 then substring exist else not

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = 'Hello world';
let b = 'ld';

let position = a.indexOf(b);
```

this will give you the position of first occurrence of string b in string a and if it is not present in string a, it would give you -1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String#indexOf()`.

Based on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), `.indexOf()` for Strings accepts a `search value` parameter. If the search value is found, it returns a non-negative value. If it does not find your `search value`, it returns `-1`.

```
let word = 'Hello world!';
let query = 'world';
let anotherQuery = 'value';

word.indexOf(query); // returns 6 - which is a non-negative value
word.indexOf(anotherQuery); // returns -1
```

Which you can use it this way.

```
let isExist = word.indexOf(query) !== -1;
```

Or you can write a function for it

```
function find(haystack, needle) {
  let isFound = haystack.indexOf(needle);

  return isFound !== -1;
}

let isExist = find(word, query);
```